# justify a dictionary for both keys and values

Tags: python, function, dictionary

.

The code I have so far is just a simple:

```
def aligned(s):
    for key, value in s.items():
        print(key, ": " , value)
```

Comment: This works for this specific dict, I wonder if there is a way to do it for any dict? Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You can use ***rjust*** to display the key and ***ljust*** to display the value but first you will need to calculate the maximum length for key strings and value strings. I will go like so:

```
def aligned(s):
    max_key_length = max(map(len, s.keys()))
    max_value_length = max(map(lambda x: len(str(x)), s.values()))
    for key, value in s.items():
        print(key.rjust(max_key_length), str(value).ljust(max_value_length))
```